# How to decompose $\sin(a+b)$ into $f(a)+g(b)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I wonder how to decompose  $\sin(a+b)= f(a)+g(b)$ so that $f, g$ were not infinite series assuming that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers?

Comment: Why do you think such functions $f, g$ exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it needs to work for all $a$ and $b$, then you can't.

Because $\sin(0+0)=\sin(0+\pi)$ you would need to have $g(0)=g(\pi)$. But then you can't get $\sin(\frac\pi2+0)$ to differ from $\sin(\frac\pi2+\pi)$ (which it ought to; the former is $1$ whereas the latter is $-1$).

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$${d\over dA}{d\over dB} (f(A) + g(B)) = {d\over dA} (g'(B)) = 0$$

Whereas

$${d\over dA}{d\over dB} (\sin(A+B)) = -\sin(A+B)$$

Therefore it cannot be possible to decompose $\sin(A+B)$ to $f(A) + g(B)$.